# newly created hyper links are automatically convert to https

Tags: c#, .net, https

I have site that is running on **https**. I am facing one problem here when I trying to add new Hyper links on my site. These are automatically converted into https. Can anyone know why this happening ?

Comment: Please show your work first.. People can't read your mind.

Comment: My site have ability to post your comment on wall like facebook. If User want to post a link like www.abc.com , My code is creating this as link as following way <a href='http://www.abc.com'>http://www.abc.com</a>
The Code responsible for this is:

 if (post.Contains("www."))
            {
             
                post = post.Replace("www.", "http://www.");
            }

 This is my expected behaviour But new link are creating with https instead http. It is making new hyper links as :
<a href='https://www.abc.com'>https://www.abc.com</a>

Comment: it's magic!!! - no its not but seriously, this question isn't answerable without you providing information. HOW is your site taking the domain information and rendering it. There are just so many ways to represent hyperlinked text across the .net platform it would be impossible to even guess what you might be trying to do. - Please update your original question with code samples and what you have already tried. This page might help `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask`

Comment: Yes, It looks like magic :) I have tried upper code at my local test project this as working fine but when I have tried It on the live site it makes all hyperlinks in post with https. Please note my site is running on secure sockect layer https